# How to format the script that is packed to single line?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

sometimes the script(in the web-browser) is packed in one line `function a(b){if(c==1){}else{}}`. I tried to find something that would show it in normal way

```
function a(b) {
   if(c==1) {
   }
   else {
   }
}
```

but didn't found. Is there is some code or program that can do it?

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to do it for you

```
function a(b) {
    if (c == 1) {} else {}
}
```

And [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) seems to do the same formatting as well.

Comment: i would prefer the ssame joseph told

Answer (score 1):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) has a wonderful whitespace fixer/beautifier called "TidyUp". It returns this for your line (as an alternate solution to jsBeautifier, since I can barely spell it):

```
function a(b) {
    if (c == 1) {} else {}
}​
```

Which is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JS Minifier by Franck Marcia, where you can minify your js code in the browser (That is if you don't want a pretty code, else use jsFiddle like the others said). The aggressive Level spits out the following code:

```
function a(b){if(c==1){}else{}}
```

Link: http://fmarcia.info/jsmin/test.html